# Remove hyphens and underscores from image files within a windows network share folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, character, strip

As a part of my job I frequently receive large numbers of image files that contain hyphens or underscores which need to be removed.

I have tried using the below code, and it worked when I ran it within a folder on my dropdox. However, I tried running it on a folder in our network share, and it is not working properly. It looks like it is stripping the characters from a few of the files, and then delivering the message "A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found."

Running the file again strips the characters from a few more files before delivering the same message.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%j in (*.*) do (
set filename=%%~nj
set filename=!filename:_=!
set filename=!filename:-=!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
)
```

Comment: Maybe you have a filename that has no extension.

Comment: `if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" if not exist "!filename!%%~xj" (ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj") else (echo "!filename!%%~xj" already exitst)` and replace simple `echo` command with a more sophisticated code snippet to treat the case. And instead of `for %%j in (*.*) do` try static `for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /B /A:-D *.*') do`